# "cleaning up" of double values' impreciseness

Tags: c#

I have a program that is getting data a third party API, but sometimes the double values I got are represented in a "imprecise" (or too precise) way, eg.

0.3 represented as 0.2999999999999

0.04 represented as 0.03999999999999

This causes problems especially when I wanted to do equality comparisons. Is there a way to clean up the "impreciseness" of the double values as I receive them?

What I can think of:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        double x = 0.2999999999999; //from third party API          
        x = cleanDouble(x); //x=0.3
    }

    private double cleanDouble(double input)
    {
        string s = input.ToString("0.##########");
        double.TryParse(s, out input);
        return input;
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Converting a double to string and back to double doesn't seem very efficient or elegant to me.

Thank you very much.

P.S. For the purpose of my application, the precision of the values I will get won't be more that 0.00000001.

P.P.S. I won't know beforehand what value I will get from the third party API. It could be 0.0004999999999, 0.039999999999999, 100.049999999999999 etc.

P.P.P.S. For the purpose of this question, I need to use double, not decimal.

Comment: You never compare doubles on equality actually. But compare if they are close enough for your app in a particular case to be treated as equal.

Comment: Side note: you may want to read on how double/float values are present in computers... There really no 0.3 (unlike 0.25) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you're coming up with data like that, so this may or may not apply, but would you be safe to just `Math.Round(double, int)`? It's not exactly elegant, it's really more a Band-Aid over the problem. But if there's really not way to clean up what you're pulling in, that would work.

Since you say it doesn't need to exceed the preciseness of 0.00000001, you could just do

```
Math.Round(value, 8);
```

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes. :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the numbers alone and write your own compare function.   Something like:

```
Bool Test = IsRoughlyEqual(.0001, .0002, .01);

public bool IsRoughlyEqual(double NumA, double NumB, double Tolerance)
{
    double Result = Math.Abs(NumA - NumB);

    if (Result > Tolerance)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be much faster than converting the double to a string and then reparsing into a double.

```
private double cleanDouble(double input)
{
    double ceil = Math.Ceil(input);
    if (ceil - input < 0.00000001)
        return ceil;

    double floor = Math.Floor(input);
    if (input - floor < 0.00000001)
        return floor;

    return input;
}
```

Keep in mind that some numbers can't be 100% accurately represented by a double, so some tolerance is needed.